# Operator Button Text alignment

Tags: scripting, interface

In my addon if `bl_region_type = TOOL_PROPS`, the operators text is not aligned.

[image]

Where as if `bl_region_type = TOOL` the text is aligned on the left side.

[image]

Why is this and how could I align the text in operator while `bl_region_type = TOOL_PROPS`?

Comment: No - check the answer on the linked page.

Comment: (in the internal C code) this is controlled by the layout engine and current theme. It means only in C I can but not in Python?

Comment: Thats correct..